# Where to use @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory")

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I'm trying to build a simple (read-only) web app with GWT and RequestFactory, and I can't work out how to get rid of following warning:

```
warning: The domain type DDisplay is not default-instantiable. Calling RequestContext.create(DDisplayProxy.class) will cause a server error.

  Add @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.
```

The problem being, I have pasted @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") above every possibly relevant class, interface and method, but I still get this message.

As my requestfactory is read-only, I'm not going to call RequestContext.create, so this is not a concern. It would just be nice to get rid of the warning (without creating a DDisplay locator class).

On the server side I have a domain object DDisplay, and a DAO, DDisplayService.

```
public class DDisplay {

    public String getTitle () {
        return "title";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DDisplayService {

    public DDisplay getDisplayByUUID (String uuid) {
        return new DDisplay ();
    }
}
```

I have the following for RequestFactory:

```
@ProxyForName("com.foobar.server.display.DDisplay")
public interface DDisplayProxy extends EntityProxy {

    String getTitle ();
}
```

and

```
public interface DisplayRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {

    @ServiceName(
            value="com.foobar.server.display.DDisplayService"
        ,locator="com.foobar.server.display.SpringServiceLocator"
    )
    public interface DisplayRequestContext extends RequestContext {
        Request <DDisplayProxy> getDisplayByUUID (String id);
    }

    DisplayRequestContext display ();
}
```

Can anyone tell me where to put the @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to get rid of this error please? Or is there another way of doing this - do I just need to add a never-used Locator class?

thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the source where the error message come from, it appears that you can add this to your EntityProxy, `DDisplayProxy`. Something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("requestfactory")
@ProxyForName("com.foobar.server.display.DDisplay")
public interface DDisplayProxy extends EntityProxy {

    String getTitle();
}
```

This from reading the source of `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.DomainChecker#visitType`, which if `currentTypeIsProxy` is true and there is no locator, and the type isn't instatiable, the warning is emitted. From inside of `state.warn(...)` (which is given the proxy type element), it checks for the presence of the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation on that type.

Comment: Hi Colin, thanks for your advice on this - I#m certain you are right here. I still have the problem, but I think this may be down to some configuration elsewhere that I haven't yet worked out. I've built my project from  net.ltgtlgwt.archetypes - modular-requestfactory (so shared interfaces are in their own project) and I think I've broken something along the way to do with annotation processing. I'll post anything more I work out on this. thanks again for your help. Jim

Comment: Hmm, good to know. My one guess (having learned something new today) is that if javac doesnt see the file as changed, it actually won't have access to `@SuppressWarnings`, so you might get this error (for example) in eclipse when you change another RequestFactory type without doing a clean build...

Comment: Ok - so I've finally traced this down to issues with using eclipse and maven at the same time - the 2 don't don't play that nicely together- my error has gone (not quite sure at what point it diisappeared) but under eclipse the code is sprinkled with errors whilst it runs fine under maven. I'm my current case this is due to apt processing I think - the generated sources are created in different folders under eclipse and maven.

Comment: That's odd - I know if they are both building together, they can "disagree", but if you run a maven build, usually all you need is to refresh eclipse (or something - its been several years since I used eclipse even part time), not rebuild again. I do know from testing this year that the m2e-apt plugin is needed if you want eclipse to run annotation processors in a way that is consistent with maven, but in my experience they both always build to the same place. This new issue might be worth a new question, so other people can help?